# Link to Adwords MCC from my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-ads-api

I am using Adwords API and now I want to add a link to MCC in my rails application's admin area.

How can I add a link to Adwords MCC from my rails application. I have adwords API access. The admin should land to MCC after clicking the link (not on login page).

Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a tricky one; if the user is not logged into their Google account, you can't get past the login screen. May be if you switch your app to use OAuth instead of ClientLogin, and require that the user logs into their Google account before using your app, then clicking the adwords link should take you to the welcome page instead of login page. But it is at best a hack that may or may not work, IMO it is not worth the trouble.

Cheers,
Anash